# ClassCastExcpetion after using Double.intValue() in lambda expression

Tags: java, swing, classcastexception

So, I have a strange problem:

I have a `JSlider` and a `JSpinner`, the Slider uses int values while the spinner accepts double values. Now I want to 'connect' them by using change listeners:

```
slider.addChangeListener(e -> spinner.setValue(slider.getValue()));
spinner.addChangeListener(e -> slider.setValue(((Double) spinner.getValue()).intValue()));
```

But for some weird reason I get a ClassCastException:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Double
at rt.Main.lambda$rotateTo$29(Main.java:318)
at javax.swing.JSpinner.fireStateChanged(JSpinner.java:458)
at javax.swing.JSpinner$ModelListener.stateChanged(JSpinner.java:386)
at javax.swing.AbstractSpinnerModel.fireStateChanged(AbstractSpinnerModel.java:119)
at javax.swing.SpinnerNumberModel.setValue(SpinnerNumberModel.java:447)
at javax.swing.JSpinner.setValue(JSpinner.java:354)
at rt.Main.lambda$rotateTo$28(Main.java:317)
at javax.swing.JSlider.fireStateChanged(JSlider.java:432)
at javax.swing.JSlider$ModelListener.stateChanged(JSlider.java:350)
at javax.swing.DefaultBoundedRangeModel.fireStateChanged(DefaultBoundedRangeModel.java:364)
at javax.swing.DefaultBoundedRangeModel.setRangeProperties(DefaultBoundedRangeModel.java:302)
at javax.swing.DefaultBoundedRangeModel.setValue(DefaultBoundedRangeModel.java:168)
at javax.swing.JSlider.setValue(JSlider.java:531)
at rt.Main.lambda$rotateTo$29(Main.java:318)
at javax.swing.JSpinner.fireStateChanged(JSpinner.java:458)
at javax.swing.JSpinner$ModelListener.stateChanged(JSpinner.java:386)
at javax.swing.AbstractSpinnerModel.fireStateChanged(AbstractSpinnerModel.java:119)
at javax.swing.SpinnerNumberModel.setValue(SpinnerNumberModel.java:447)
at javax.swing.JSpinner.setValue(JSpinner.java:354)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicSpinnerUI$ArrowButtonHandler.actionPerformed(BasicSpinnerUI.java:654)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:289)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:289)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6539)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6304)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4535)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
```

I noticed the following:

- Using `System.out.println(spinner.getValue().getClass())` I get `class java.lang.Double`.
- I checked the parameters on the `spinner.setValue()` method and it takes a primitive `int`.
- Using the code `spinner.addChangeListener(e -> System.out.println(((Double) spinner.getValue()).intValue()));` does work without throwing an exception and prints an int.
- I also tried different solutions like `Math.round()` or `(int) Double.doubleValue()`, until now nothing worked.

If anyone has an Idea why this happens please tell me!

**Edit:**
While trying around some more I found out that `slider.setValue(((Number) spinner.getValue()).intValue())` does work, but I would still like to now why?
I checked the class returned again and it still is: `java.lang.Double`!
Any help appreciated

Comment: are you sure that `spinner.setValue()`, first line, is not setting it to an `Integer` and then immediately calling the listener on second line, with that `Integer` *stored* as value? (try `spinner.setValue((double) slider.getValue())`) {hopefully the listener are not called if the value is not changed, otherwise *never ending story*}

Comment: @user85421 The class returned by ```spinner.getValue().getClass()``` still says ```java.lang.Double``` and printing the value without any cast still shows a double (and like mentioned in the edit section, no endless call occurs, otherwise this would probably result in an ```OutOfMemoryError```).

Comment: have you done that inside the listeners, after the second one has been activated? Stack trace is showing that both were called (hard to believe that Java is throwing an exception stating that `Integer` cannot be cast to `Double` if no `Integer` is there....)

Comment: @user85421 Yeah, but they terminate after some calls, awt probably has a fail save for this, also look what I wrote about printing the calles

Comment: or, I *suspect* (= if memory doesn't fail), change listeners are only called if there is effectively a change, setting same value doesn't count as one

Comment: @user85421 probably something like that. While I see where your going with your solution it's odd that the printed class stays the same, also if what you said is true, entering a double value in the spinner would result in it being dumped as soon as the event is triggered, but it stays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first listener

```java
slider.addChangeListener(e -> spinner.setValue(slider.getValue()));
```

is setting the value of the spinner to an `Integer` - `slider.getValue()` returns an `int` that is boxed since `spinner.setValue()` requires an `Object`.

Probably<sup>*</sup> you are using a `SpinnerNumberModel` which accepts any `Number` for its properties (see javadoc). Since the value of the spinner was changed (programmatically by first listener), its listener is also called, causing the exception since it now have an `Integer` as value.

Simple test showing that the spinner gets an `Integer`:

```java
JSlider slider = new JSlider(0, 0, 9, 5);
JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(5.0, 0.0, 9.0, 1.0));

slider.addChangeListener(e -> spinner.setValue(slider.getValue()));
spinner.addChangeListener(e -> slider.setValue(((Number) spinner.getValue()).intValue()));

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new Object[] { slider, spinner });
System.out.println(spinner.getValue().getClass());
```

move the slider and press `OK` - it will set the spinner value to an `Integer`.

<sup>* missing such minimal complete example in question</sup>

---

Correct solution, IMHO:

```java
slider.addChangeListener(e -> spinner.setValue((double)slider.getValue()));
spinner.addChangeListener(e -> slider.setValue(((Number) spinner.getValue()).intValue()));
```

I left the cast to `Number` as [metallurg suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59120815/85421) since the model is designed to work with `Number`.

Answer (score 1):

Spinner return Integer. Slider expects Double. You can convert Integer to Doble as following:
`spinner.addChangeListener(e -> slider.setValue(((Number)spinner).doubleValue()));`

Integer is a subclass of Number. That's why it is allowed to cast it to Number. The Number has method `doubleValue()`.

Comment: Using ```spinner.getValue().getClass()``` returns: ```java.lang.Double```, how can it be an Integer? Also ```slider.setValue()``` is implemented like ```slider.setValue(int n)```.

Comment: Check your parenthesis that caused the problem

Comment: @Jayr Why should my parenthesis be the problem? ```((cast) variable).methodCall()?```

Comment: Sorry meant "that may have caused". I was wrong. For the possible cause, maybe at first run its ok. But after slider is set with value (int), it is set to spinner. Spinner.getValue then would return an int. Mentallurg answer will work even in such condition